# How Databricks manages Spark Sessions in a colaborative cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Consider we have several people working on a Databricks cluster in a colaborative way. Spark Context and Spark Session happens in the background.

Are they sharing the same Spark Session by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark Session Isolation is enabled by default. Users can disable session isolation by setting `spark.databricks.session.share` to `true`

You can set it in Spark config in advanced cluster option:

[image]